# Error with osm_cartography on ROS indigo

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I install osm_carography using "git clone" since my work space, and when i execute the example (viz_osm.launch) ,show me the next error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/andres/ros_ws/open_street_map/osm_cartography/scripts/viz_osm", line 65, in 
import osm_cartography.cfg.VizOSMConfig as Config
ImportError: No module named osm_cartography.cfg.VizOSMConfig

Please can somebody help with an error?

Regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218801/error-with-osm_cartography-on-ros-indigo/) by [Fenix](https://answers.ros.org/users/22603/fenix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some things to check:

- Did you build your workspace after cloning the source?
- Did you `source devel/setup.bash` from the workspace after building it?

**UPDATE**: this is a catkin package, you don't build it with rosmake. Instead:

```
$ cd ~/ros_workspace
$ catkin_make
$ source devel/setup.bash
```

After that you can run the program.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2015-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fenix](https://answers.ros.org/users/22603/fenix/) on 2015-10-08**:
Hi joq,

I made this:

- cd ~/ros_workspace.
- git clone //repository/package_name\.
- cd package_name.
- rosmake.

To update the package later on, run the commands:

- roscd package_name.
- git pull.
- rosmake --pre-clean.

Please, How do you install the osm_cartography package?

Regards

**Comment by [Fenix](https://answers.ros.org/users/22603/fenix/) on 2015-10-09**:
Hi again joq,

Thanks a lot for your help and time. Problem solved.